JFrog artifactory migration from old POD to new POD [7.15.4 intance to 7.90.14 rev instance K8s pods]
Hello can someone help me please!!
I am facing issue while exporting system to azip with the error saying 500 internal.
enter image description here
The following are the settings that I have used.
enter image description here
Following is source jfrog OSS version.
version: Open source license 7.15.4
2024-10-28T00:12:00.003Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [b1a9d8cc54c7b0d6] [ualCacheCleanupServiceImpl:119] [art-exec-2          ] - Starting cleanup of virtual repositories cache
2024-10-28T00:12:00.740Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [b1a9d8cc54c7b0d6] [ualCacheCleanupServiceImpl:127] [art-exec-2          ] - Completed virtual repositories cleanup: removed 154 cached files.
2024-10-28T01:06:19.282Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [ifactoryApplicationContext:709] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Beginning full system export...
2024-10-28T01:06:19.291Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [ifactoryApplicationContext:736] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Creating temp export directory: /tmp/20241028.010619.tmp
2024-10-28T01:06:19.292Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [ifactoryApplicationContext:743] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Using backup directory: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp'.
2024-10-28T01:06:19.296Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:654] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Exporting config...
2024-10-28T01:06:19.649Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:1384] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Exporting serviceId to file
2024-10-28T01:06:19.651Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:1366] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Triggering export in access server...
2024-10-28T01:06:19.998Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [ifactoryApplicationContext:937] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Note: the etc exported folder has excessive permissions. Be careful with the files.
2024-10-28T01:06:19.998Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [a.s.u.SignedUrlServiceImpl:295] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Exporting URL signing key...
2024-10-28T01:06:20.001Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [r.s.RepositoryServiceImpl:1023] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Exporting repositories...
2024-10-28T01:06:20.002Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [r.s.RepositoryServiceImpl:1023] [art-exec-7          ] - Exporting repositories...
2024-10-28T01:06:20.006Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - artifactory-build-info export started with 295 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/artifactory-build-info'
2024-10-28T01:06:20.815Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - artifactory-build-info export finished with: 295 Items exported (292 files and 3 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 811.72 millis IPS: 363.43 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/artifactory-build-info'
2024-10-28T01:06:20.816Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - example-repo-local export started with 1 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/example-repo-local'
2024-10-28T01:06:20.819Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - example-repo-local export finished with: 1 Items exported (0 files and 1 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 3.83 millis IPS: 261.17 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/example-repo-local'
2024-10-28T01:06:20.831Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - local-release export started with 2534 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/local-release'
2024-10-28T01:06:25.480Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - local-release export finished with: 2534 Items exported (1657 files and 877 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 4.66 secs IPS: 543.71 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/local-release'
2024-10-28T01:06:25.501Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - local-snapshot export started with 6425 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/local-snapshot'
2024-10-28T01:06:29.412Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - local-snapshot exported 3000 items (2738 files 262 folders 763.23 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:06:35.100Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - local-snapshot exported 6000 items (5377 files 623 folders 623.73 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:06:35.560Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - local-snapshot export finished with: 6425 Items exported (5760 files and 665 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 10.08 secs IPS: 637.46 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/local-snapshot'
2024-10-28T01:06:35.562Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - confluent-cache export started with 215 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/confluent-cache'
2024-10-28T01:06:35.838Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - confluent-cache export finished with: 215 Items exported (120 files and 95 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 277.16 millis IPS: 775.72 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/confluent-cache'
2024-10-28T01:06:35.860Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache export started with 28459 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/jcenter-cache'
2024-10-28T01:06:38.813Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 3000 items (105 files 2895 folders 1008.41 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:06:42.473Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 6000 items (221 files 5779 folders 904.29 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:06:47.340Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 9000 items (428 files 8572 folders 782.53 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:06:51.880Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 12000 items (542 files 11458 folders 748.06 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:06:55.848Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 15000 items (749 files 14251 folders 749.65 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:06:59.132Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 18000 items (903 files 17097 folders 772.74 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:07:03.499Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 21000 items (1146 files 19854 folders 759.2 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:07:07.455Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 24000 items (1254 files 22746 folders 759.1 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:07:10.475Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache exported 27000 items (1403 files 25597 folders 779.52 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:07:12.361Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - jcenter-cache export finished with: 28459 Items exported (1442 files and 27017 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 36.52 secs IPS: 779.23 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/jcenter-cache'
2024-10-28T01:07:12.362Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - maven.google-cache export started with 1 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/maven.google-cache'
2024-10-28T01:07:12.364Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - maven.google-cache export finished with: 1 Items exported (0 files and 1 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 2.46 millis IPS: 406.05 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/maven.google-cache'
2024-10-28T01:07:12.395Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:79] [art-exec-7          ] - mvncentral-cache export started with 9932 nodes to: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/mvncentral-cache'
2024-10-28T01:07:18.892Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - mvncentral-cache exported 3000 items (1458 files 1542 folders 459.61 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:07:24.520Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - mvncentral-cache exported 6000 items (2995 files 3005 folders 493.6 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:07:29.982Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93] [art-exec-7          ] - mvncentral-cache exported 9000 items (4542 files 4458 folders 510.84 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2024-10-28T01:07:31.958Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d7c123b0dff1c62f] [a.r.d.i.DbRepoExportHandler:89] [art-exec-7          ] - mvncentral-cache export finished with: 9932 Items exported (5022 files and 4910 folders), 0 Item skipped: (0 files and 0 folders).Duration: 19.59 secs IPS: 506.91 Target: '/tmp/20241028.010619.tmp/repositories/mvncentral-cache'
2024-10-28T01:07:31.958Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [ifactoryApplicationContext:869] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Creating archive...
2024-10-28T01:08:15.689Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [58066adb7ebb382d] [ifactoryApplicationContext:839] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Full system export completed successfully.

Even tho.. I got 500 internal error in logs i got it successful. So I moved on to next step.
When trying to upload to new instance i got this error.
Destination version : 7.90.14 rev 79014900 [OSS]
enter image description here
It should be uploaded system properties, Even i have the zip file with artifactory.properties, jfrog artifactory says it doesnot exists.

For your current issue, unzip the export and try again.
In general I do want to note that Jfrog do not recommend importing from one version to another version, though it can work, so you can test it out.
See the warning here:
We do not recommend that you import and export between different versions of Artifactory.
(Instead it is recommended to import to same version then upgrade that system. But It is fine to test what you are doing as it can work also.
